# Call script only if a GET variable doesn't exist in URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Howdy Stackoverflowies,

For specific requirements, I would like to implement a website in which I want to exclude the call to Google Analytics script if a specific variable is defined in the URL.

I scoured the web looking for a simple solution, but all those that I read appeared too complicated, involving the manual creation of functions in Javascript...etc.

The simplest (but sort of dirty) solution I found so far involves the call of a PHP snippet, as such:

```
<?php
        if ($_GET['dnt']===null)
        {
        ?>
        <!-- Recaptcha Script -->
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script> 

        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=my_id"></script>
        <script>
        console.log('test');
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());

          gtag('config', 'my_id');
        </script>
        <?php } ?>
```

However, with this piece of code, the script is always called, no matter what I do... I even tried replacing the if clause with

```
if(!isset($_GET['dnt']))
```

...but the result is exactly the same.

Do you have any SIMPLE alternative to do this?
My source for the code above is this article: http://www.daniloaz.com/en/5-ways-to-exclude-your-own-visits-from-google-analytics/#comment-159117

Thank you.

Comment: What URL are you using? Are you sure you are properly setting ``dnt``?

Comment: I'm using it like this: localhost?dnt=1
My whole website is just one page, the index page. :)

Comment: You can use 'if(!isset($_GET['dnt']))' to echo the javascript Google script tag.  This way you get the script tag loaded when no variable is defined.

Comment: What does ``var_dump($_GET)`` show?

Comment: @CharlesEF I tried your solution, the result is exactly the same... the code is always called.

Comment: @kmoser I tried to do what you're asking me, I don't know if I'm doing this right, but I get nothing at all:

if (!isset($_GET['dnt']))
{
 ob_start();                    
 var_dump( $_GET );          
 $contents = ob_get_contents(); 
 ob_end_clean();               
 error_log($contents);     
[...]

The error log is activated on WAMP but remains empty. I also tried to echo a "<script>console.log('var dump: '.$contents.');</script>"; but I got the .$contents. displayed raw in the console...

Comment: I made some progress moving my PHP code out of my index.html file in a specific PHP file and calling it with AJAX. Here's what I get from var_dump($_GET):

<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>C:\wamp\www\server\php\CallGoogleAnalytics.php:5:</small>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
  <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>

Comment: If you're passing something in the query string,  ``$_GET`` should not be empty. How about dumping ``$_REQUEST``?

Comment: I get the exact same thing...
Here's what I have now: I deported the PHP code in the PHP file and put this in my index.html file: $.get('./server/php/CallGoogleAnalytics.php', function(data) {
    document.write(data);
   });
   </script>
But I get a weird message about a missing ')' on the first line of my index.html page (<html lang="en">)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been investigating that issue ever since I posted that message, and I just can't get PHP to read my $_GET variables properly despite testing a ton of things. I couldn't identify the reason, and since no one's been able to help, here's how I ended up working around the issue in jQuery:

```
var $_GET = {};

document.location.search.replace(/\??(?:([^=]+)=([^&]*)&?)/g, function () {
    function decode(s) {
        return decodeURIComponent(s.split("+").join(" "));
    }

    $_GET[decode(arguments[1])] = decode(arguments[2]);
});

//If variable "dnt" is defined, bypass Google Analytics
if(typeof $_GET["dnt"] == 'undefined')
{
    var gA = "<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'><\/script><script async src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=my_id'><\/script><script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}gtag('js', new Date());gtag('config', 'my_id');<\/script>";
    $('body').append(gA);
}
```

It's pretty ugly but does the job well.